# NamedList with Deep Pagination

Tags: csv, solr, pagination

```
QueryRequest req=new QueryRequest(solrQuery);
NoOpResponseParser responseParser = new NoOpResponseParser();
responseParser.setWriterType("csv");
searcherServer.setParser(responseParser);
NamedList<Object> resp=searcherServer.request(req);
QueryResponse res = searcherServer.query(solrQuery);
responseString = (String)resp.get("response");
```

I use the above code to get the output in CSV format. The data I am trying to fetch is huge (In billions). So I want to include deep pagination of SOLR and get chunks of CSV output. Is there a way to do? Also, with the current version of SOLR (I cannot upgrade) I have to use the above code to get CSV output.

I tried the below way to fetch the results.

```
searcherServer = new HttpSolrServer(url);
SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery();
solrQuery.setQuery(query);
solrQuery.set("fl","field1");
solrQuery.setParam("wt", "csv");
solrQuery.setStart(0);
solrQuery.setRows(1000);
solrQuery.setSort(SolrQuery.SortClause.asc("field2"));
```

In the output from the above code has wt as javabin. So I cannot get the CSV output.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways.

1. use Solr [export](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Exporting+Result+Sets) request handler (or add it) and `wt=csv` parameter. Just to be clear, this is an [Implicit Request Handler](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Implicit+RequestHandlers) usually available even in older Solr versions and specifically designed to handle scenarios that involve exporting millions of records.
2. implement deep paging correctly. I suggest Yonic post [paging and deep paging](http://yonik.com/solr/paging-and-deep-paging/), it easier than you think. But after you'll have correctly implement, you also need to create the csv file by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was:

```
SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery();
solrQuery.setQuery(query); //what you want to fetch
QueryResponse res = searcherServer.query(solrQuery);
int numFound = (int)res.getResults().getNumFound();
int rowsToBeFetched = (numFound > 1000 ? (int)(numFound/6) : numFound);
for(int i=0; i< numFound; i=i+rowsToBeFetched ){
 solrQuery.set("fl","fieldToBeFetched");
 solrQuery.setParam("wt", "csv");
 solrQuery.setStart(i);
 solrQuery.setRows(rowsToBeFetched);
 QueryRequest req=new QueryRequest(solrQuery);
 NoOpResponseParser responseParser = new NoOpResponseParser();
 responseParser.setWriterType("csv");
 searcherServer.setParser(responseParser);
 NamedList<Object> resp=searcherServer.request(req);
 responseString = (String)resp.get("response"); //This is in CSV format
}
```

Pros:

1. Since I don't get the result at once, it was faster.
2. The output was csv.
3. Hitting solr multiple items isn't costly.

Cons:

1. The result is not unique, meaning there can be repeated data based on what you are fetching.

To get unique results, you can use facets.

Thanks!